# Active class not applied when clicking on an li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I want to give the active class when I click `<li>`, but it doesn't work.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="main-menu-navigation" data-menu="menu-navigation">
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="auth"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>Sign in</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="signup"><i class="feather icon-user-plus"></i>Signup</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="services"><i class="feather icon-list"></i>Services</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="terms"><i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>Terms</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```js
$('.navbar-nav').on('click', 'li', function() {
  $('.navbar-nav li.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Please include your jquery, without it we can't tell you whats wrong

Comment: Your code is working fine. The problem is that your `a` links are changing the page, so the class you add is lost when the new page is displayed.

Comment: As @RoryMcCrossan has mentioned, your `<a>` links are loading to a new page completely. Either prefix a `#` to your `href` values if they are anchor links to sections of the same page, or add some on-load code so that the active class will be added to the correct page upon loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you don't have any code posted, so I can't tell what is the matter with your code. Here is what I can infer

```
// register a listener on click of any item with the class nav-item
$(document).on("click", ".nav-item", function(){
    // turn all nav-items "active" class off
    $(".nav-item").removeClass("active");
    // turn on the "active" class for this item
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: It would be nice to know why a down-vote was given. I can't learn anything without criticism.

Comment: Maybe it's because without the OP's code we can't know what's wrong and can't provide a good answer, so answers like this would maybe not answer the "real" question. I didn't downvote you though.

Comment: Indeed. And now that the OP has added their code, this can be deleted as it's already been implemented and does not work for the same reason.